# Expressing the punctured affine plane as a quotient.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-stacks

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0012219.pdf) Toen states (on p.50) that the punctured affine plane $\mathbb{A}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$ is equivalent (as a stack) to a quotient stack $[\mathrm{sl}_{2}/\mathbb{G}_{a}]$. It is not even clear to me what the $\mathbb{G}_{a}$-action on $\mathrm{sl}_{2}$ could be. Can anyone offer any hints about how to prove this?

Comment: Perhaps $\mathbb{G}_a$ is acting by tranalsation of a root subalgebra?

Answer (score 2):

$SL_2$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and the stabilizer of the point $(1,0) \in \mathbb{A}^2$ is the subgroup 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & t \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cong \mathbb{G}_a.
$$
Consequently, $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\} \cong SL_2/\mathbb{G}_a$.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer Sasha. Can you possibly elaborate on how to express this in the language of stacks?

Comment: Whenever you have a FREE group action on a variety, the quotient stack is isomorphic to the quotient variety.